# How do I get flex-box to work on bootstrap

Tags: css, navbar

I've been learning Bootstrap 5 for sometime now and tried to combine Bootstrap with flex-box to create a navbar that collapses.
But for some reason the flex-box I used for the navbar links is displaying a **white line** that I cant get rid of. I've tried changing the background-color of the flexbox but it still didn't work,
I think it may be something with the bootstrap but cant find a way to fix it for 2 hours. If someone can tell me how to fix this with the bootstrap or just tell me what I did wrong I would appreciate. Many thanks!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scrap.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>scrap</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark confusing">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand col-md-2 col-3">
                <h2>Protocole</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <div class="navbar-nav nav-tabs col">
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">pages</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">about</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="btn btn-light col-md-8 col">Login</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.confusing{
    height: 10vh;
}
.nav-tabs{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.nav-item{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line for `.nav-tabs` css class: `border:none;`